# How to automatically build a header with include of every file from folder c++ Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been making a game engine using c++ 17, visual studio and cmake.

I've made a GUI for a level maker. It requires entitylist.h, which has `#include` of every header in entities/  folder.

If a user wants to make a custom entity Foo and add it to a level:

> They add Foo.h into entities/

> They add `#include "Foo.h"` into entitylist.h

> They compile and can place an entity to the level in levelmaker GUI

However, this is stupid. Users should not need to fiddle with entitylist.h. This fiddling is dangerous and wastes time. Other engines do not have such a requirement.

**Is there a way to add `#include` of every file in entities/ folder into entitylist.h automatically on build?**

Comment: In CMake collecting all files in a directory could be performed with [file(GLOB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem). This command creates a list variable containing all files, so you could iterate over this variable and write corresponding line into `entitylist.h` using [file(APPEND)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#writing).

Comment: It's not hard to write a small program that iterates over files in a directory, and outputs a file with an `#include` for each one.  Optionally, it can write to a temporary file and only update the output file if it detects a change of content.    That said, I'd query why your GUI requires an entitylist.h that needs continual updating - if the GUI needs a list of headers in a directory, why can't it iterate over the directory itself?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Perhaps it'd be better if you provided an answer showing the CMake style to do it? My answer is probably easy to translate into CMake for someone knowing CMake enough. I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I removed makefile tag, I need specifically a cmake solution

Comment: @Peter Can you provide an example code that ´iterates over directory itself' that works in cmake?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `entitylist.h` into a build target of its own. In `make` lingo it would look like this:

```
# collect all the header files in the entities directory
ENTITIES=$(wildcard entities/*.h)

# the build target entitylist.h depends on all the header files:
entitylist.h : $(ENTITIES)
        @echo "#pragma once" > entitylist.h; \
        for ent in $(ENTITIES); do \
            echo "#include \"$$ent\""; \
        done >> entitylist.h
```

Comment: This leads to Cmakelist exiting with code 1, leading to compile error. 

I'm not at all savvy with CMakeLists, so I can't really debug this issue.

Should entitylist.h be in a certain subfolder, should it exist at all when I build?

Comment: @eflwap Yes, this is a `makefile` so it would need to be processed by gmake or similar. If you run `make -f the_above_file`, it should produce `entitylist.h`. `entitylist.h` doesn't need to exist before - but the targets needing it should have a dependency towards it. Hopefully Tsyvarev or someone else CMake savvy can provide a pure CMake answer .